# Angularfire2 Missing FirebaseObjectObersable

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  test: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.test = db.object('test').valueChanges();
  }
}
```

So I have this code but everytime I try to compile I'm getting this error

Cannot find name 'FirebaseObjectObservable'.

I assumed that was part of the angularfire2/database module?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because it is simply deprecated and doesn't exist any more in version 5. here is a quote from the official angularfire2 docs:

> AngularFire 5.0 is a refactor of the `AngularFireDatabase` module. It
>   removes the `FirebaseListObservable` and `FirebaseObjectObservable` in
>   favor of a generic based service API.

You should switch to `AngularFireObject` instead, please take a look at the official docs [Upgrading to AngularFire 5.0](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md#upgrading-to-angularfire-50).